# How do I call supportFragmentManger in a Service Class?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have created a service class to handle the locations for my app. But I have an error dialog fragment so how do I call supportFragmentManger? I have also created a class for dialog fragment within my service class.

```
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, (Activity) mContext,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {

            // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Wyntr-Beta");
        }
    }

    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;

        /**
         * Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
         */
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        /*
         * Set the dialog to display
         *
         * @param dialog An error dialog
         */
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        /*
         * This method must return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
         */
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone also help me how can I declare Location service class in Manifest

Comment: You may wish to explain, in greater detail, what a "Location service class" is. If you mean some subclass of `Service`, you use [a `<service>` element in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare it extends ServiceClass so I guess should I add it as <service> element in Manifest

Answer (score 1):

> But I have an error dialog fragment so how do I call supportFragmentManger?

Move all of this code into your activity, before launching the service. A service cannot display a fragment. You need to validate that Play Services is ready for use before you can start using its APIs from a service or other non-activity contexts.

Comment: So can I add PlayServices in my SplashScreen Activity?

Comment: @Savita: I have no idea if that would be appropriate or not. Technically, it is a better solution than trying to check for Play Services directly in the service.

Comment: My MainActivity shows skipped 80 frames I think the problem could be because of the Location calls thats why I want to move it from MainActivity to Service class. That's I wanted to know if I use PlayServices in the SplashScreenActivity would it work.

Comment: @Savita: You are not making any "Location calls" in your code listing in your question. You are welcome to make such calls in a service, assuming that you mean using the fused location API. However, **you need to show the error dialog from an activity**. How you do that is up to you. I suggest that you set up your Play Services in an activity, then delegate the location handling work to the service. You are welcome to try using an event bus, to get `errorCode` from your service to an activity to display the dialog.

Comment: Can you help me how I can manage selfcheckpermissions in Service class

Comment: @Savita: `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` should work fine with a `Service`.